# How to understand the noise specifications of amplifier?

Tags: operational-amplifier, noise, datasheet, instrumentation-amplifier

LT6370 Instrumentation amplifier has specifications as below.
[image: LT6370 Features]

How should I understand this specification? Why only 0.1 to 10 Hz is specified, why not high frequency values?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How should I understand this specification?

The chart below from the [data sheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/LT6370.pdf) clarifies understanding.
[image]

> Why only 0.1 to 10 Hz is specified,... ?

This is the region where 1/f noise (also called flicker noise) is dominant. Measuring with a filter with these corner frequencies will (should) not measure greater than \$0.2\mu V_{P-P}\$ if the GAIN is 1000.

> ... why not high frequency values?

Above 10Hz, the noise density is flat. This is the thermal noise region. Measuring at 1KHz is kind-of a standard. It is well into the flat region shown on the chart. The \$7 nV/\sqrt{Hz}\$ at 1KHz, appears on the chart on the green G=1000 curve.

The data sheet shows how to calculate the total referred-to-input (RTI) noise.

[image]

Measuring noise so that it matches the data sheet can be challenging, primarily because the measuring system has all the same noise issues.

Comment: Thank you so much

Answer (score 3):

> How should I understand this specification ?

You should understand that noise is a complicated parameter, not possible to distill down into a figure or two.

You will find it's not a specification anyway, the [data sheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/lt6370.pdf) only gives unwarranted typicals for noise.

> why only 0.1 to 10hertz is specified, why not high frequency values ?

There are several different mechanisms that generate noise in an amplifier, which give rise to different amounts of noise at different frequencies.

As such, a noise profile is usually summarised by the frequencies where the slope of the noise changes. See the graphs of noise versus frequency on page 10 of the linked data sheet, that puts frequencies to the 1/f corner.

For initial headline figures, most designers are interested in either DC and low frequency stability, or 'audio frequency' noise for which the 1 kHz noise density is relevant.

0.1 - 10 Hz has emerged as a *de facto* standard low frequency range, that includes the 1 Hz area where people might want to make manual measurements, and hints at the DC performance. Its lower frequency limit is really a measurement compromise, you don't want to tie up expensive test equipment for too long checking noise down to 10 mHz or 1 mHz. Most manufacturers supplying low noise amplifiers report this range, it then makes it very easy for designers to use a spreadsheet to reduce a long list to a short list for a large number of amplifiers, before spending more time on the details of the short list.

If you look at the full data sheet for the LT6370 amplifier, you'll see graphs of voltage and current noise versus frequency, offset drift,

Comment: Thank you so much.